# set overlay Icon to running explorer without restart

Tags: visual-c++, overlay, explorer, shell-extensions

I want to change overlay Icon of file on the basis of some status.
if file status get changed the overlay Icon should change.
for example: If file is locked overlay icon related to locked should set & If release it should set different overlay icon.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7484/How-to-overlay-an-icon-over-existing-shell-objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set overlay Icon needs to implement a [IShellIconOverlayIdentifier interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761265(v=vs.85).aspx)

write registry entries in `registry` for `COM` `dll` registration and one more `registry` requires for overlay icon identifier registration see below:

```
Key:"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\TestShellIconOverlayIdentifiers"
with default value [CLSID_of_registered_DLL]
```

After this some functions need to call while registration to insert overlay Icons in system memory of already running instances of explorer for that I found the answer on below post.
 [How can I programmatically refresh Windows Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777714/creating-a-c-non-blocking-timer-in-windows)

See the function `"bool RebuildIcons()"` on [TortoiseCVS - ShellUtils.cpp](http://tortoisecvs.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tortoisecvs/TortoiseCVS/src/Utils/ShellUtils.cpp?revision=1.70&view=markup&pathrev=MAIN)